# React native: how to avoid double special characters?

Tags: regex, react-native

I have a text input which represents some title. Letters and numbers are allowed. As well as **some** special characters. For instance:

```
"Don't use" -> valid sequence
"Don''t use" -> invalid sequence
"Don'?!%^t use" -> invalid sequence
"Be quiet!" -> valid sequence
"Be quiet!><" -> invalid sequence
"123 Your name?" -> valid sequence
"123 Your name?;'" -> invalid sequence
```

That is if the text input contains letters, numbers and **ONE** character among `'?!` I consider my text input as valid. If the text input contains **any** from the other special characters **OR** two consecutive from the allowed special characters, I consider it as invalid.

What my regular expression should be?

I was thinking that I should probably do two tests. For instance something like:

```
var notAllowedCharacters = /[ `@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};:"\\|,.<>\/~]/;
if (notAllowedCharacters.test(text)) {
      //do somethin
    }
```

Then test again:

```
var alowedCharacters = /[ `'?!]/;
    //how do I test if these characers are allowed to be used only surrounded by letters?
    if (alowedCharacters.test(text)) {
      //do something
    }
```

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: It depends on what you want to allow between "words" like `^\w+(?:'\w+)*(?:\s+\w+(?:'\w+)*)*[.?!]?$` https://regex101.com/r/G7SmTh/1 Or `^\w+(?:[.?!' ]\w+)*[.?!]?$` allowing one of the allowed characters between words https://regex101.com/r/YuDBxq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only 1 of the listed characters can occur between "words" and optionally a character except a space at the end:

```
^\w+(?:[ `'?!]\w+)*[`.?!]?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `` (?:[ `'?!]\w+)* `` Optionally repeat 1 of the listed characters and again 1+ word characters so there can not be 2 adjacent ones.
- `` [`.?!]? `` Optionally match 1 of the listed characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CaYHO4/1)

```js
const regex = /^\w+(?:[ `'?!]\w+)*[`.?!]?$/;
[
  "Don't use",
  "Don''t use",
  "Don'?!%^t use",
  "Be quiet!",
  "Be quiet!><",
  "123 Your name?",
  "123 Your name?;'"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```